# Proving equicontinuity of a subset of the dual space of a Hausdorff convex space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am having to self-learn functional analysis/topology and I am working through "Topological Vector Spaces" by Robertson and Robertson.

I am given $E$, a Hausdorff convex space. $E'$ is the dual of $E$ that consists of all continuous linear functionals on $E$.

The text states (without proof) that $A' \subset E'$ is equicontinuous iff there is a neighborhood $U \subset E$ with $|<x,x'>| < 1$ for all $x \in U$ and $x' \in A'$.

I am having difficulty in proving this. By definition of equicontinuity, I know that for any subset $V$, that is open in $\mathbb R$ (real space), there is a common $U$ that is open in $E$ such that every functional in $A'$ maps $U$ into $V$.

How do we go from having to consider any subset $V$ that is open in $\mathbb R$ (could even be an open set that is not connected, i.e. could be the union of disjoint open sets) to only considering the connected open set $(-1,1) \in \mathbb R$?

Honestly, I do not have an idea as to how to proceed on this and hence have little to show in terms of what I have done so far.

Comment: Every open subset of $\mathbb R$ is the union of open intervals. Does this help?

Comment: @Jochen, Thanks. Going by definition of equicontinuity, let V be an arbitrary open set in $\mathbb R$. If V contains 0, then there is some e, with 0<e<1, such that (-e,e) belongs to V. Then, eU would suffice. The case where 0 does not belong to V seems more complicated. Here, I would have to produce a common U that is open in E such that every functional in A' maps U into V. So, scaling seems fine, but translation seems problematic. Also, it is not clear to me where the fact that E is Hausdorff and a locally convex space are needed in the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that your definition of equicontinuity is correct. A family $F$ of function from $E$ to $\mathbb R$ is equicontinuous if for every $x\in E$ and $\varepsilon >0$ there is a neighbourhood $W$ of $x$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ for all $y\in W$ and $f\in F$.

I think you won't have difficulties to show that in your situation (you need neither Hausdorff nor local convexity).

Comment: Using your hint, given the hypothesis that there is a neighborhood U  in E with |<x,x'>| < 1 for all x in U and x' in A', I have to show, as per the definition in your answer, that given x in E and e>0, there is a neighborhood W of x such that |<y,x'>-<x,x'>| = |<y-x>,x'>|< e for all x' in A' and y in W. Letting W = eU + x is an open set around x and we are done. Is this right? Thanks for your hint!